# How does NeoVim's native LSP client compare with plug-ins that implement that protocol?

Tags: neovim, lsp

NeoVim v0.5 will include a native [LSP (Language Server Protocol)](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) implementation.

See Greg Hurrell (wincent)'s [Screencast #87: Neovim's built-in LSP client](https://youtu.be/3jl8a5Wo2l0) covering it.

How does it compare with existing Vim plug-ins that implement LSP clients, such as:

- [vim-lsp](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)
- [LanguageClient-neovim](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim)
- [vim-lsc](https://github.com/natebosch/vim-lsc)

What are the main advantages of providing a native implementation rather than using third-party plug-ins for this purpose?

Comment: All I got is one implementation == less fragmentation of features. Hm, plus it can be compiled instead of interpreted

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the Neovim LSP is pretty low level and still requires lots of configuration for each language. The plugins do this work for you, and are often better configured and tested because there are more eyeballs looking at them. These days (2023) you'd be better off with https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig.

That said, if you wanted to configure everything without a plugin, you could. You would need to install the language server on your computer, then configure the LSP to use use it for specific file types. Then you'd want to configure the actual capabilities of the language server - some of which are non standard (e.g. vscode-language-server).